# Can't import RecyclerView after adding the support library to build.gradle & syncing project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I'm using Android Studio Beta 6, and I've added the `RecyclerView` support lib to the end of my `build.gradle`.  **My app is already running fine**, I just need to use the `RecyclerView` now.

Here's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        addCustomFieldsToBuildConfig(release)
        addCustomFieldsToBuildConfig(debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21+'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile files('libs/com_nineoldandroids.jar')
    compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v2_1_7_crashonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/adobeMobileLibrary-4.8.1.jar')
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'

    // I WANT TO ADD THESE:
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
}
```

I've tried specific versions of `RecyclerView` such as '21.0.2' but they all result in the same issue.  I ask Android Studio to sync the gradle settings, and there are no errors.

But as you can see, **I can't autocomplete the `v7` after `support`**:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply typing RecyclerView in a method and seeing if Studio will suggest where to import it from?

Comment: Yep, all `RecyclerView` references are highlighted red and hovering over them says "Cannot resolve symbol RecyclerView"

Comment: My only thought is that the file you're editing is in a different project than the one whose gradle file you modified.

Comment: I can't believe this but I had to "Make" the project first.  Once I did that, it was able to resolve everything. I have not had to do that for previous lib additions in the `build.gradle`, a simple sync got everything up to date.

Comment: Did Studio not prompt you to sync again immediately after changing the gradle file?  There should be a yellow banner that shows after any change.

Comment: Yeah, I got the prompt every time I tweaked the version numbers, it completed the sync successfully each of those times.

Comment: What you are using in XML layout for `RecyclerView` if you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that this will help someone in a similar situation with Android Studio, but I had to go to `Build -> Make Project` before it was able to resolve references to the `RecyclerView` class.